# Concurrent user Login in spring mvc

Tags: spring, security, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I am currently having a problem in implementing concurrent user session in spring mvc. My requirement is that "I have a web application which uses spring MVC, and I have my own login form and I have not implemented spring security yet(which means I have not configured any role based user restriction in my web application). I want only one user with same username to be logged in from a machine. I have surfed all over the net , but couldn't find any useful links nor example project(without role based).

My Requirement:

1. One user per session
2. No role based restriction
3. Have my own login form and once the user logs in , user object(which contains username an password) is stored in session object
4. If user tries to login for second time , previous user session should be terminated and new user(second user) should be allowed to home page.

Can some one please provide me a solution, links or example project for my requirement ? Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just go ahead and use Spring Security? It will take care of deactivating sessions for you. You can use your own login form and not restrict any of your endpoints based on roles.

You can configure the max number of sessions like so:

Comment: Yes I want to use spring security, But all the examples i found over net is of more confusing and my requirement was done with role based(which is not my requirement, all my pages in my application is accessible for all the users). To be more precise , i dint find any examples nor link over the internet for my requirement. Any links would be more useful !!

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response! You can define roles on a per-URL basis and an acceptable role is "ANONYMOUS" which will not require any existing user principle.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/anonymous.html

You can still store user information in the user principal and have default info for any non-authenticated users. Does this cover your requirements?